# what is the best way of investment which gives returns forever?

Tags: investment-property

What is the best way that I can invest money so that I can always get returns? 
Would it be to set up an FD in a bank, to buy land, to buy a rental house, to buy a field, or maybe to purchase gold?
Are there any better investments?
I want to earn from that investment forever so I don't have to invest again and again on it.

Comment: Note that gold doesn't produce any return.  Indeed, if you have a significant quantity, you may incur negative return from the costs of secure storage.  Depending on your age and the amount you have to invest, an annuity might be appropriate.  Or just put the money in a mutual fund.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the best way that I can invest money so that I can always get
>   returns? Would it be to set up an FD in a bank, to buy land, to buy a
>   rental house, to buy a field, or maybe to purchase gold?

Forever is a long time.

Of the options you listed, the only one guaranteed to generate returns is a bank account. The returns may well be very small, but (absent an economy-wide financial failure) you will get the stated return.

Land doesn't always retain its value, nor do rental houses or fields. Gold clearly fluctuates.

But you would be better served to think about goals and how you can attain them.

What do you want to do with the "returns"? If you are trying to set yourself up for purchasing a home, paying for college, or retirement, then the small returns on a bank account may be insufficient. And in that case you might be better served by worrying more about the size of the returns you need than the certainty of them.

There may be many "better investments" if you more clearly define what you expect to achieve by your investment.

Comment: yes iam much bothered about the size of the returns

Comment: how about rental scheme?

Comment: @user145764 - start with your goals. Only then can you know the best way to achieve them. "Returns forever" may be a means to achieve a goal, but by itself that isn't a goal.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way that I can invest money so that I can always get
>   returns?

If you want something that doesn't require any work on your end, consider having a fee-only financial planner make a plan so that your investments can be automated to generate a cash flow for you or get an annuity as the other classic choices here as most other choices will require some time commitment in one form or other. Note that for stock investments there could be rare instances like what happened for a week in September in 2001 where the markets were closed for 5 days straight that can be the hiccup in having stocks. Bonds can carry a risk of default where there have been municipalities that defaulted on debt as well as federal governments like Russia in the 1990s. Real estate may be subject to natural disasters or other market forces that may prevent there always being a monthly payment coming as if you own a rental property then what happens if there aren't tenants because there was an evacuation of the area? There may be some insurance products to cover some of these cases though what if there are exceptionally high claims all at once that may have an insurance company go under?

> Would it be to set up an FD in a bank, to buy land, to buy a rental
>   house, to buy a field, or maybe to purchase gold?

What investment of your own time do you plan on making here? Both in terms of understanding what your long-term strategy is and then the maintenance of the plan. If you put the money in the bank, are you expecting that the interest rate will always be high enough to give you sufficient cash to live as well as having no financial crisis with the bank or currency you are using?

> Are there any better investments?

You may want to reconsider what assumptions you want to make and what risks you want to accept as there isn't likely to be a single solution here that would be perfect.